# How divide space between Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

[image]

I need to create Bottom Navigation with two menu item. but the view ratio is 30:70 and text gravity is in centre.
one menu contain image and text one is only text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_symbol1"
    android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_title1"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_symbol2"
    android:title="@string/bottom_navigation_title2"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```

Below code in main layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation1" />
```

Comment: paste your xml hear

Comment: i edit question

Comment: @PrinceKumar did u solved it?

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes using custom layout. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to create Bottom Navigation with two menu item. but the view ratio is 30:70 and text gravity is in centre. one menu contain image and text one is only text

**`AFAIK`** you can not achieve using menu better to create custom layout for this

Sample code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_message"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#24edf1"
        android:text="Message" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#24edf1"
        android:background="#dedbdb"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BUY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple LinearLayout and weightsum diving your weight with 70-30 to avoid complexity BottomNavigation menu. Set one view with vertical linear layout using ImageView and TextView and another view with only TextView. Parent of both views will be horizontal  LinearLayout.